# How to reduce the height of a button with CSS?

Tags: css, html, button

I am new to CSS. I have the following style for a tag button. How to reduce the height of the button? I tried changing it but it didn't help.

My code:

```
.tag-btn {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #F08080;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: try reducing the padding and line-height

Comment: You are using height as well as line-height, and it is likely they are conflicting at similar sizes on the screen. Try removing height and changing line-height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `height` completely and try adjusting `line-height`

```
.tag-btn {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #F08080;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dgy3k95e/)**

Answer (score 4):

Reduce your height as well as padding and remove the line height.

```
.tag-btn {
font-size: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 5;
position: relative;
padding:3px;    
margin: 0;
height: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
background-color: #F08080;
border: none;
color: #fff;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/804LnLma/)

Comment: You have also removed the line-height attribute here.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai - This pulls the letters to the bottom of the element

Comment: @DineshAppavoo did you check that demo link? Did you removed the line height  property?

Comment: Yes. When I copy  the demo link content the letter placement is going down.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the `line-height` and `height`

**CSS**

```
.tag-btn {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 22px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #F08080;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/1phy3bvh/)**

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the padding and line-height to decrease the height

Also read about the box model in css to understand more

https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 1):

your .tag-btn is an inline-element,your can change the padding or line-height to change the height of btn,if your want to change the height directly, you can change the element to inline-block

```
.tag-btn {
  padding: 5px 10px; //your code is 10px
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Decrease "padding" css property. Make it one pixel and try.

```
padding: 1px;
```

Answer (score 1):

your .tag-btn is an inline-element

- your can change the padding
- your can change the line-height
- you can change the element to inline-block, if your want to change the height directly

every way will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `line-height` and `padding` from your CSS. Thereafter, you can manipulate the height.